# Combobox in CMFCMenuBar does not open

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

How to populate help combo box

```
class MyFrame : public CFrameWnd {
...
CMFCMenuBar m_menuBar;
...
};

int MyFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct )
{
    int res = CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct);

    m_menuBar.Create(this);
    m_menuBar.EnableHelpCombobox(1, _T("Test"), 150 );
    m_menuBar.CreateFromMenu(hMenu,FALSE,TRUE);

    CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton* combo = m_menuBar.GetHelpCombobox();
    combo->AddItem("Item 1");
    combo->AddItem("Item 2");
    combo->AddItem("Item 3");
    combo->AddItem("Item 4");

    combo->EnableWindow(true);
    combo->SelectItem(2,FALSE);
    combo->SetCenterVert();
    combo->SetDropDownHeight(150);

    return res;

}
```

The item text "Item 3" which was selected is shown combo field but nothing happnes when I hit the button on dropdown. `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::AddItem(...)` returns valid index and `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::Count(...)` returns 4 as expected.